# SNMP: Configuring/Enabling SNMPv3 on Cisco IOS and SNMP Agent

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, snmp, cisco-ios-12, cisco-ios-15

I have been configuring and using SNMP v2c on Cisco routers.

Due to the obvious advantages in SNMP v3, I am planning on enabling SNMP v3 on SNMP v3 supported devices.

Could someone let me know:

1. The commands used to configure SNMP v3 on an Cisco IOS?
2. The configuration required on the SNMP v3 agent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have a pretty simple writeup over at [Networklessons](http://networklessons.com/network-management/how-to-configure-snmpv3-on-cisco-ios-router/), but in-depth information on how it works are on [Cisco's site](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/snmp/configuration/xe-3se/3850/snmp-xe-3se-3850-book/nm-snmp-snmpv3.html). It can be as complicated and secure as you want it. Your 2 questions are one and the same.

A barebones config would be like this:

**Create a group**

```
R1(config)#snmp-server group MYGROUP v3 priv
```

**Attach a user to a group**

```
R1(config)#snmp-server user MYUSER MYGROUP v3 auth md5 MYPASS123 priv aes128 MYKEY123
```

If you aren't looking to restrict access to specific MIBs, then this is all you really need.

Answer (score 0):

```
snmp-server view viewRO iso included
snmp-server group CCNA4 v3 priv read viewRO access ACL_SNMP_SERVER
user ccnauser CCNA4 v3 auth sha CCNA4123 priv aes 128 CCNA4123
#snmp-server enable traps
#ip access-list standard ACL_SNMP_SERVER
permit 10.10.1.48
```

Comment: You should improve your answer by explaining it.