# SNMPv3 Setup - Cisco 3750

Tags: cisco, snmp, cisco-commands, cisco-3750

I am not a network guru by any means but need to setup our router/switch to use SNMPv3.  I am installing What's Up Gold on our system and configured the settings (changed for this post) as follows:

```
Username: testusername
Authentication
Protocol: sha
Password: testpassword
```

On my router, I have ran the following:

```
snmp-server view TESTVIEW mib-2 included 

snmp-server group TESTGROUP v3 auth read TESTVIEW 

snmp-server user ALL TESTGROUP v3 auth sha testpassword 

snmp-server host 192.168.12.2 version 3 auth testusername 

snmp-server host 192.168.12.2 informs version 3 auth testusername
```

After inserting these commands, I go back to the SNMP software and attempt to discover the seed address 192.168.12.254, the gateway, but cannot receive a valid connection.  I turned debugging on the router but receive nothing in `show log`.  I setup SNMPv2 to test and see if it could even see that and it worked just fine...I am guessing I am missing something in my router configuration...any ideas?

Comment: It isn't clear what error message you're receiving or what application you're using.  Can you give it a go with [snmpwalk](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpwalk.html) and then tell us what error message you're getting? Here's an example of what a [simple setup](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6844/snmp-configuring-enabling-snmpv3-on-cisco-ios-and-snmp-agent/6846#6846) looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your username is wrong in your commands, try substituting `testusername` for `ALL`

```
snmp-server view TESTVIEW mib-2 included 
snmp-server group TESTGROUP v3 auth read TESTVIEW 
snmp-server user testusername TESTGROUP v3 auth sha testpassword
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with glallen that you should be substituting **testusername** for **all** in your *snmp-server user* command.

But if that doesn't work, for troubleshooting purposes, I would start with a more basic SNMPv3 configuration, see if it works and then start adding a more complex configuration from there.

My suggestion start with:

```
snmp-server group TESTGROUP v3 auth
snmp-server user testusername TESTGROUP v3 auth sha testpassword
```

per:  http://networklessons.com/network-management/how-to-configure-snmpv3-on-cisco-ios-router/#ixzz2rzU2BWJa